# Including Web Fonts With Moovweb

Tags: webfonts, google-webfonts, moovweb

I am trying to include Google Fonts in my Moovweb site via @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700);  and then including the tag 'Oswald' in font-family.  I have done this before with static sites, but for some reason it is not working for me.  I am not sure if I am placing the code in the right file?  Seems like a simple fix, if someone could provide some guidance it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To answer my own question, I added insert_top("link", rel: "stylesheet", href:"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald") to the html.ts file and then included the font in font-family of _base.scss. If this is not best practice please advise.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hey Danny, just FYI it's encouraged to answer your own question as you would any normal stackoverflow post (there's an "Answer Your Own Question" box you should have). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using @import ? Can you not create the link tag on head of your file?

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Is there any message on the console?